# Forcing user to install the required packages in R

Tags: r, package

I am currently building a R packages and the package required the package `caret`. I added the `caret` in the "Import" section in the "Description" in my package. However, `caret` is not loaded when I run the package, and this causes an error when I run my function. Is there a way that the function can automatically download the package `caret` when the user run it?

Comment: Try using `Depends: caret` instead of `Imports: caret` in the `DESCRIPTION` file

Comment: I don't think this is necessary Allan, I think it might rather be asMax suggested in his answer, that the package is not added to the NAMESPACE (which needs also to be done besides writing it in the description). But of course, if it still doesn't work after getting the NAMESPACE file right, this would probably worth a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides adding `caret` to your package description, you also need to import it wherever it's being used.  You can do this by adding the following line to the top of your source code files.

```
#' @import caret
```

Or one thing you might consider if you don't need all of the package's functionality is just importing the necessary functions like so.

```
#' @importFrom caret train knn3
```

Comment: Addition to this good answer:  if you are not using roxygen, you have to make sure, caret is in the NAMESPACE file. Since what roxygen basically does is creating this NAMESPACE file automatically for you from your #' @import annotations.